# Attempt to set a non-property-list object

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm new to Xcode and this site - so apologies if I break any protocols.

I am trying to sort individuals leave taken & amended in non calendar leave-years. So not a lot of data so I'm using `NSUserDefaults`.

The 'leave-logic' works but I am having problems saving one `NSMutableDictionary` to `NSUserDefaults`.

The error is

> Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
>   "2014-01-28 00:00:00 +0000" = "A/L";
>   } as an NSUserDefaults value for key defthisYearsLeave

I just can't see where this is coming from hence all the 'NSLogs'.

Here is the problematic section of code and the console output

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSDictionary *returnedData = @{selectedDate :sourceViewController.hiddenDuty.text};
[self.thisYearsLeave addEntriesFromDictionary:returnedData];
    NSArray *debugValue = [self.thisYearsLeave allValues];
       for(id value in debugValue)
       {
          if([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) NSLog(@"value is an NSString: %@", value);
       }
self.thisYears = [[self.thisYearsLeave allKeys]mutableCopy];
       for(id key in self.thisYears)
       {
          if([key isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) NSLog(@"key is an NSDate: %@", key);
       }
self.leaveCountThisYear = self.thisYears.count;
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.thisYears sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                 ^(id obj1, id obj2)
                 {
                    return [(NSDate*) obj2 compare: (NSDate*)obj1];
                 }
                 ];
for(int i = 0; i < self.thisYears.count; i++)
{
   self.sortedArrayStrings[i] = [mediumdateFormatter stringFromDate:sortedArray[i]];
   NSLog(@"entry in sortedArrayStrings: %@", self.sortedArrayStrings[i]);     //  √
}        
[defaults setObject: self.sortedArrayStrings forKey:@"defsortedArrayStrings"];    //  √

[defaults setObject: self.thisYearsLeave forKey:@"defthisYearsLeave"];
/* X why is this non property-list?  */
```

And the console return:

```
2014-01-28 00:38:46.995 MyWorkingDays[60106:70b] value is an NSString: A/L
2014-01-28 00:38:46.996 MyWorkingDays[60106:70b] key is an NSDate: 2014-01-28 00:00:00 +0000
2014-01-28 00:38:46.996 MyWorkingDays[60106:70b] entry in sortedArrayStrings: 28 Jan 2014
2014-01-28 00:38:46.997 MyWorkingDays[60106:70b] Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
"2014-01-28 00:00:00 +0000" = "A/L";
} as an NSUserDefaults value for key defthisYearsLeave
2014-01-28 00:38:46.999 MyWorkingDays[60106:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception            'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert non-property list object {
"2014-01-28 00:00:00 +0000" = "A/L";
} for key defthisYearsLeave'
```

I'm sure I'm missing something blindingly obvious to a more experienced coder!

Comment: Many thanks. My first use of NSUserDefaults and I took in that everything had to be property-list but not the restriction on the key. Sadly as this annual leave we are using - it is the NSDate that is unique so flipping the dictionary is out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSDate cannot serve as the key in a property list dictionary. You either have to flip that dictionary around (that is, make `@"A/L"` the key and the date the value) or find another way to reorganize your data so that the date is never the key in a dictionary.

Comment: I can save the leave NSDates as NSStrings and reconvert on retrieval.